# How do I insert an empty line?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

How can I add an empty line between to paragraphs, thus separating them more strongly?

Comment: Note that if this question is interpreted as "how do I add a single blank line somewhere without changing the normal paragraph spacing in the rest of the document" then the duplicate does not apply (but the answer below does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm almost sure this is a duplicate but `\vspace{\baselineskip}` should do the job. You can also put a factor in front of the `\baselineskip` to get more or less extra space.

As hinted at by David though:
**Don't use this code unless you know what you are doing!**
In all probability you will only make your typesetting worse, not better.

Comment: @Dominik, although this is the accepted answer you shouldn't normally be adding explicit space within the document. See the answers in the linked duplicate question. TeX has a built in mechanism for automatically adding space between paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, I should have used a "Don't do this unless you know what you are doing" disclaimer. Oh wait, I can edit.